# Keeping State of Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

Is there a way to keep a state of a vue so that when navigated back it is shown?

Example:

1) I'm on Page A, search something, items are loaded, I scroll down and pick item 34 from the list.

2) Now Page B opens with information about the item. I click back but end on an empty Page A.

What I would want is the search results and ideally the scroll position from when I left that vue.

Is that possible out of the box in vue2 or do I have to code all of that myself?

Comment: Yes, you have to use vuex

Comment: The OP wants to keep state over page navigation back and forward, not usual state management Vuex is typically about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So you want to somehow vuejs to remember to scrollPosition.As always that is very simple with vue.

The scroll behavior can managed by Vue-Router.I'll show you an example.

**The Page component with 2 scroll positions**

```
<template>
  <div>
      <div id="data1" style="height:700px;background:blue">
        First scroll position
      </div>

      <div id="data2" style="height:700px;background:yellow">
        Second scroll position
      </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

**The component which navigate to page component**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <router-link 
    tag="button"
    :to="link"
    >
    Navigate to Page in scroll Position 2
    </router-link>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
    data: () => ({
      link: {
        name: 'Page',
        hash: '#data2' //<= important,this adds the #data2 in url
      }    
    })
  }
</script>
```

**Now your route file have to look like this:**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Page from '@/components/Page.vue'
import NavigationButton from '@/components/NavigationButton.vue'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/Page',
      name: 'Page',
      component: Page,
    },
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'NavigationButton',
      component: NavigationButton
    },
    //other routes
  ],
  mode: 'history',
  scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) {
    if(savedPosition){ //when use press back button will go at the position he was on the page
        return savedPosition
    }
    if(to.hash){ //if has a hash positition to go
        return { selector: to.hash } //go to the page in scrolled Position
    }
    return { x:0, y: 0 } //go to the page in scroll = 0 Position
  }  
})
```

That i understood by your question,but i am not sure your asking about that.Anyway if i am right,dont forget also to take a look to official vue-router documentation about scroll behavior.[See here](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/scroll-behavior.html)